# how to print log in flutter windows vc++ code?

Tags: windows, flutter, logging, visual-c++, printf

I write flutter to write a windows software, so I want to add same logs which shows in console in fultter windows vc++ code, I used printf and std::out to print logs, but android studio console not any print log, how to add logs in flutter windows vc++ code?

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to print text to the console you can use
`print('Text')`.

But if you want to access the advanced features of the DevTools console you need to use the Console class from
`dart:html: Console.log('Text')`

Example:-

Use print() to print a string to the console of your browser:

```
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var value = querySelector('input').value;
  print('The value of the input is: $value');
}
```